# Will the Identity column be same in different HSQLDB tables

Tags: hsqldb

I m pretty new to HSQLDB and have a question on Identity columns.

If I have two tables and both tables have Identity columns, then are there values generated by a single sequence or is there a possibility that both tables can have similar values in identity columns?

Also is there a possibility to trigger a Sequence whenever a insert happens into any table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hyper SQL uses the same model as most other (all?) SQL implementations.  The sequence of identity values in one table is entirely independent from other tables.

As example lets say you have TableA and TableB both have an Id column and this column is an identity.  When you insert into TableA the Id value, for that table, is calculated and assigned.  However this value has nothing to do with TableB and no changes are made to TableB at all.

If you have a process that inserts into both tables at the same time, then you will see an apparent link as the identity values will be same (assuming you are using the same identity model on both and started at the same point).  This "apparent link" is just that though, there is no relationship at all.